# When exactly is a thread_local variable declared at global scope initialized?

Tags: c++, multithreading, initialization, storage

For example:

```
#include <thread>

thread_local int n = 1;

void f()
{
    ++n; // is n initialized here for each thread or prior to entering f()?
}

int main()
{
    std::thread ta(f);
    std::thread tb(f);

    ta.join();
    tb.join();
}
```

It's still not entirely clear from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) when is n initialized.

Comment: When the thread is initialized.

Comment: For each thread when it (the thread) is initialized.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253584/when-is-a-thread-local-global-variable-initialized

Comment: It does look confusing a bit. What's _local_ is the _storage_ for n for each thread. But the scope of n (i.e. its _visibility_ in code) is global.

Comment: The initialization itself takes place as the answers (here and in the linked question) describe: before its use. When exactly? Not specified by the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple enough, and all according to specification. `n` is going to be initialized whenever the new thread is run - before you enter any thread-specific functions.

To be exact, it is going to be initialized three times.