# Is this a valid way to guarantee thread_local initialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-local-storage

Consider the below testcase:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

thread_local struct Bar
{
     Bar() { std::cout << '*' << std::endl; }
    ~Bar() { std::cout << '~' << std::endl; }
} bar;

struct Foo
{
    void baz()
    {
        (void)&bar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.baz();

    std::thread t(&Foo::baz, &f);
    t.join();
}
```

[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73bb48a84bb19ebd) it works as I intend, with the seemingly useless statement `(void)&bar` apparently counting as "use" and ensuring that `bar` is constructed in any thread that invokes `baz()`.

**Is this guaranteed, or should I do something more?**

I'm hoping to use a class like `Bar` to wrap some per-thread initialisation required by a C library I'm going to use, with a minimum of boilerplate. `baz()` is already a function that any thread will call to do work with the C library, so this could effectively be a transparent solution.

Comment: Taking the address is _odr-use_ but I'm concerned about potentially permitted optimisations, given that I literally never do anything with the object, despite the side effects of construction and destruction (let's face it, there are examples of exceptions to that in the language)

Comment: Since the constructor of Bar gets called, there's no way any optimizer will remove that statement.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: It's a little more complicated than just looking at the declaration and saying the constructor gets called: remove `(void)&b` and you'll find that it isn't. The guarantee I'm looking for is that adding `(void)&b` back in ensures that it _is_.

Comment: I asked something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253584/when-is-a-thread-local-global-variable-initialized). The standard guarantees that a thread-local is initialized before its first odr-use, and `&bar` is indeed an ODR-use. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was indeed referring to the `(void)&bar` statement, which you shouldn't remove of course.

Comment: @sbabbi: If that's so, then I don't think you're missing anything :)